# Getting linking errors when using header CPP

Tags: c++, dll

I made a class that helps read .csv files in visual studio 2019 (The class is called CsvReader).

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <fstream>

namespace csv
{
    class CsvReader
    {
    private:
        std::string fileName;
        std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> content;
        std::unordered_map<std::string, int> fieldIndex;
        std::unordered_map<int, std::string> indexField;

    public:
        CsvReader(const char* file);
        void loadFile(const char* file);
        std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> items();
        int fieldToIndex(std::string field);
        std::string indexToField(int index);
        size_t fieldCount();
        void print();
        void trim(const char symbol);
    };
}
```

I want to use that class in a different solution to read a .csv file. The configuration type of the CsvReader is Dynamic Library (.dll).

[image]

When I try to #include "CsvReader.h" in the project that I want to use the CsvReader in, the program recognizes the class, but when I run the program, I get two linking errors.

> LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public:_thiscall csv::CsvReader(char const*)" (??0CsvReader@csv@@QAE@PBD@Z) referenced in function_main

and

> LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public:void_thiscall csv::CsvReader::print(void)" (?print@CsvReader@csv@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function_main

I don't really understand what I am doing wrong.

The program that I want to use the class in:

```
#include "../../Classes/CsvReader/CsvReader/CsvReader.h" // I know it's a pretty long path
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    csv::CsvReader test1 ("TestCases/test.csv");
    test1.print();

    return 0;
}
```

The .CPP file in which I define all the functions is pretty big, and I don't know if that one is necessary.

Comment: The project that your `main()` is in needs to link to `CsvReader.lib` at compile/link time so that at runtime it will open `CsvReader.dll` to perform runtime linking.

Comment: If you can, you should have all the projects under one solution and add in all the correct references between projects and VS will sort out the linking process for you.

Comment: But if I want to share my class with other people on say GitHub, they can't do that right? And if I want to use my class in multiple projects, I would get a really big solution. How do I link CsvReader.lib to the project that my main() is in?

Comment: If other people on, say, GitHub use your code, then it will be up to them whether to include your code directly into their projects, or as a separate static or dynamic lib. For you, if `CsvReader` is a completely separate solution, then you need to have a folder with a `headers` sub folder for the headers and a `lib` folder for the `.lib` and `.dll` files. Then you tell the compiler about the location of the `headers` folder and the linker about the location of the `lib` folder and the name of the `.lib` file. (I think, then, at runtime it sorts out the linking to the `.dll` automatically)

Comment: How do I tell the compiler and linker about the locations? And is there a way to make Visual Studio automatically put headers into a headers folder and .lib and .dll files into a lib folder?

Comment: Now you are asking different questions. Perhaps others have already asked them on Stackoverflow. But it’s all there in the project settings. But, also, no I don’t think there is a way of having VS automatically copy artifacts to other locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, there are at least two projects involved: a DLL called *CsvReader* and an executable (I'm going to call it *CsvUser* until I'm otherwise corrected).

Before attempting to build *CsvUser*, you should make sure *CsvReader* is built. Also pay attention to whether the build is set to "Release" or "Debug", and whether it is set to x86 or x64.

It looks like "Release" is being used and for simplicity, I'm going to assume x86. After that build, there should be a Release folder above your *CsvReader* (the solution directory for your *CsvReader* project).

Once you have your Release Folder (wherever it is), Open up the Properties window for the *CsvUser* Project.

Go to "Configuration Properties" --> "VC++ Directories" --> "Library Directories". Enter the location of the *Release* folder for the "CsvReader" Project.

That will let the compiler know where the libraries for the CsvReader are. Now it needs to know which library to look at.

In the Properties window, go to:

"Configuration Properties" --> "Linker" --> "Input" --> "Additional Dependencies". Make sure that "CsvReader.lib" is included.

This Github of mine is a basic demo of my experience: https://github.com/TrecApps/DLL-Demo

Note that my projects are within the same solution. I haven't tested DLL/Application interactions from two different solutions, so I don't know of additional complications that might emerge from that.

Also, since two solutions are involved, make sure that the solutions are on the same page regarding Release/Debug and x86 vs x64.

Comment: Thank you! It now works! I did have to change the configuration type from a dll to a lib, I don't think that that really matters though.